# Java Generics missunderstanding

Tags: java, generics

Why is it that a generic `T` cannot be used as a return type of `class` if `T extends Class`.

Example:

```
public class Foo<T extends Bar> {
    Bar[] array = new Bar[200];

    Optional<T> forIndex(int index) {
        return Optional.ofNullable(array[index]);
    }
}
```

`T` is required to extend `Bar` Which  means that `T` should never have a casting problem, or am I mistaking this? Could somebody elaborate.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You got it the wrong way around. Each `T` is a `Bar`, but not each `Bar`is a `T`. `T` is more specialized than `Bar` (each dachshound is a dog, but not each dog is a dachshound). This means, that `return Optional.ofNullable(array[index]);` tries to match a `Bar` on a `T`, which is not possible.

What you can do is making only the method generic:

```
public class Main {
    Bar[] array = new Bar[200];

    Optional<? super Bar> forIndex(int index) {
        return Optional.ofNullable(array[index]);
    }
}
```

You might want to look at [Oracle's tutorial on Wildcards](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/wildcards.html) as well as the [PECS (Producer `extends` - Consumer `super`) mnemonic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2723397/what-is-pecs-producer-extends-consumer-super)

---

Comment: Seems like this is just going to turn into a nasty situation with a bunch of abstract methods. `Oops:` I wrote the example in the question box :P

Comment: If only generic arrays were easier to use.

Comment: The erased nature of Java generics assures that arrays and generics don't mix well: arrays are covariant and retained, generics are invariant and erased.